# C# How to read all the data in a datagridview and put it in a listbox?

Tags: c#

I want to read all the data from a datagridview when a button is clicked and then put it in a listbox. I came this far but everytime It's not working and I don't know why. I have tried everything

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        DataGridViewCell c = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j];
        if (c.Value != null)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(c.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We need more details. What doesn't work? Also, please don't post your code as a screenshot, post the text instead.

Comment: are you sure there are 9 things to add?

Comment: it seems that you are running along the diagonal in your datagridview. Is this intended?

Comment: No I do not have 9 things to add, ( the number 9 is just an example )

Comment: It is not doing anything. I get the following error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: if you dont have 9 things your code will fail - you also make a loop variable but are getting like column 1 from the first row, 2 from the 2nd, 3rd from the 3rd.. really is this what you wanted? I doubt it

Comment: ** error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" ** is a very important information. It is not: **" It is not doing anything  "** . it is throwing an exception!

Comment: which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: I need from the first row, cell 0,1,2,3, and from the second row cell 0,1,2,3 and so on

Comment: The exception is throwing at the "string data" line.

Comment: read [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to use code block on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get the following error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
>
> The exception is throwing at the "string data" line.

I guess one of the values in your `DataGridView` has the value `null`. When you try to call the `ToString()` method on the property `Value` in:

```
string data = dgvOverzicht.Rows[getal - 1].Cells[i].Value.ToString();
```

it throws the exception.

One way to work around this is to check whether `Value` is `null` and if not then go ahead and call the `ToString()` method:

```
int getal = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    getal++;
    DataGridViewCell  c = dgvOverzicht.Rows[getal - 1].Cells[i];
    if (c.Value != null)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(c.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The for loop that you use will only visit the diagonal of your grid. If you want to get all Cells you need 2 for-loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        DataGridViewCell c = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j];
        if (c.Value != null)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(c.Value.ToString());
        }
    }                
}
```

Comment: I do not get the error anymore but It only shows 1 row and 2 cells :S? I have to get all of the information in a listBox. That is why i tried using a for loop, but somehow its not working

Comment: does your `DataGridView` show a value in every cell? I cannot imagine, because you stated that you get a `NullReferenceException`. This is the value that you are missing.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your datagridview? the information is inconsistent up to now. Because then you should not get a `NullReferenceException` in the "** the "string data" line. **"

Comment: This is a screenshot of my datagridview when running the application. And (yes I have to use the checkboxes).

Comment: @Alegou20 what is with the 4-th row?

Comment: I don't know? when I add ( for example 3 more things to the DGV ) on the end there always comes an empty row. No clue why

Comment: @Alegou20 " only shows 1 row and 2 cells " if you use your for-loop as you posted, then you go along a diagonal. This is why you get the result you see. You need second nested for-loop if you want to run through all cells of all rows.

Comment: I am missing the second row, first cel and the third row, cell1,2

Comment: This is the screenshot of the things i see in the listbox. [IMG]http://i68.tinypic.com/23k57wk.png[/IMG]

Comment: @Alegou20 please check my comment below your post, and my new edit in the answer.

Comment: Thankyou for your help! It finally works now! muchas gracias!

Comment: no problem, glad I could help. Next time try to provide a little more information :)

Answer (score 0):

your code will get a nullreferenceexception if you just have 4 columns

you use variable i to decide the cell but i can be 1 to 9 so if the datagridview does not contain the enough cells, the error will occur.

Hope this can help you.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("0", "1", "2", "3");
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "if the datagridview does not contain the enough cells"  you get a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` not a `System.NullReferenceException`